# Simplify $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!(n-k!)}.$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

Is there a way to simplify the expression

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!(n-k)!}?$$

This came up when I was trying to determine $\mathbb{P}(X+Y =r)$ given a joint mass probability $$m_{X,Y}(j,k) = \frac{c(j+k)a^{j+k}}{j!k!},$$ where $j$ and $k$ are non-negative integers and $a,c>0$ are constants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Multiply the sum by $n!$, and write $$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}=\binom{n}{k}.$$  Now try applying the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

Comment: Great hint! I get $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!(n-k)!} = \frac{2^n}{n!}$

Comment: @Eric Auld: That looks right to me.

Comment: Should the question be edited to match this answer? Specifically 
$(n-k!)$

Comment: @User58220 Done.